# Like button feature not working through parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I'm trying to implement a like button function on my app, similar to facebook or instagram, through parse. I tried using this code below and it works. When the user taps the button on an object(or in my case messages), the like goes up by 1 point. However, when the user quits the app and launches it they can like the same object again, meaning they can like as many times as they want. Do I need to edit something in this code or try a whole different method?

```
@IBAction func likeButton(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.enabled = false
    sender.userInteractionEnabled = false
    sender.alpha = 0.5

    //get the point in the table view that corresponds to the button that was pressed
    //in my case these were a bunch of cells each with their own like button
    let hitPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    let hitIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint)
    let object = objectAtIndexPath(hitIndex)

    //this is where I incremented the key for the object
    object!.incrementKey("count")
    object!.saveInBackground()

    self.tableView.reloadData()
    NSLog("Top Index Path \(hitIndex?.row)")
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can try to use an array or a relation to keep track of all of the posts that each user has likes and then when creating the post cell, check if the array or relation already contains that post. If it does, prevent the user from liking it again.

Comment: Is that something I do on Parse?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way in which I would approach the problem:

First, I would make disabling the button into its own function like so:

```
func disableButton(button: UIButton){
    button.enabled = false
    button.userInteractionEnabled = false
    button.alpha = 0.5
}
```

(And when the user presses the like button it is disabled like so:)

```
@IBAction func likeButton(sender: UIButton) {
    disableButton(sender)

    //get the point in the table view that corresponds to the button that was pressed
    //in my case these were a bunch of cells each with their own like button
    let hitPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    let hitIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint)
    let object = objectAtIndexPath(hitIndex)

    //this is where I incremented the key for the object
    object!.incrementKey("count")
    object!.saveInBackground()

    self.tableView.reloadData()
    NSLog("Top Index Path \(hitIndex?.row)")
}
```

Then I would make an attribute of users their liked posts, which is an array of strings of the `objectIds` of these posts. (Since users would probably end up liking many posts, you really should use relations, but arrays are easier to understand.  The documentation for relationships between `PFObjects` is [here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#relations).) Then, when creating the cell for each post, where `cell` is the cell you are creating, `post` is the current post in the list and `cell.likeButton` is the like button from the cell:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = YourCell()
    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    if (PFUser.currentUser!["likedPosts"] as! [String]).contains(post.objectId){
        cell.disableButton(cell.likeButton)
    }
    //Setup rest of cell
```

Comment: No. It's just a normal function.

Comment: did you also create an outlet in the cell for cell.disableButton?

Comment: If you add disableButton into the cell subclass, the dot notation will access it.